# Business Catalyst: Add "Remember Me" checkbox to Secure Zone Registration Form (as opposed to Login Form) - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, business-catalyst

**The Goal:** I have a website built in Adobe Business Catalyst where I would like to allow the user to register for a secure zone AND not have to sign in the next time they visit the website. (The system by default logs a user in when they first register for a secure zone).

**The Problem:** BC's "Remember Me" checkbox is added to the secure zone *Login Form* by default, but I'd like to add it to the secure zone *Registration Form*.

From my investigations so far I can see that the *Login Form* uses ***ZoneProcess.aspx*** in the action attribute while the *Registration Form* uses the standard ***FormProcessv2.aspx***.

**Login Form Action:**

```
action="https://mywebsite.worldsecuresystems.com/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=51&amp;Referrer=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mywebsite.com&amp;OID=16358470&amp;OTYPE=1"
```

**Registration Form Action:**

```
action="https://mywebsite.worldsecuresystems.com/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=103619&amp;OID=16347615&amp;OTYPE=1&amp;EID=0&amp;CID=0&amp;CC=NZ&amp;Referrer=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mywebsite.com"
```

Also, on submission of the Login Form (looking in Chrome Developer Tools under the Network tab) I'm seeing ZoneLoginRelay.aspx with a bunch of parameters ending with "KeepLoggedIn=True" (or False, depending on whether the Remember Me checkbox is ticked), a GET method and a 302 status.

What I want to know is whether there is any way I can add the "Remember Me" functionality to the *Registration Form*?

If the above isn't possible, would saving the login details to web storage and using auto AJAX login (so the user doesn't see the process) be a better solution?